# How can we simulate OutOfMemory: Metaspace?

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

I have a task to simulate OutOfMemory: Metaspace error intentionally. I tried different ways, but none gave me needed result. Can someone share good example for this purpose?

My first attempt (using javassist):

```
static ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();

@SneakyThrows
public void task() {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            Class cl = classPool.makeClass("task1.Test" + i).toClass();
        }
    } catch (Error er) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        log.error(er.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and settings in gradle.properties  file:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=70M

but I've got an error:

> Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the
> UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

which I couldn't catch.

My second attempt:

```
public void task() {
        try {
            URL url = new File("D:/classes").toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = {url};

            ClassLoadingMXBean loadingMXBean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();

            List<ClassLoader> classLoaders = new ArrayList<>();

            while (true) {
                ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
                classLoaders.add(classLoader);
                classLoader.loadClass("test1.Test1");

                log.info("Total: " + loadingMXBean.getTotalLoadedClassCount());
                log.info("Active: " + loadingMXBean.getLoadedClassCount());
                log.info("Unloaded: " + loadingMXBean.getUnloadedClassCount());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and it didn't work, the IDEA notified me there's law memory.

Comment: Can you actually catch that? The JVM will print it for you, no need to catch and log it. (also attempting to do stuff in that state may generate further errors)

Comment: I think I just found the example you wanted (error #4): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-outofmemoryerror-exception-java/

Comment: It still gets the same error. What do if i shoud write the test to check the needed exception, namely a requirement is to get the OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace? Can I catch it somehow and get the message from it?

Comment: *I have a task* assigned by whom and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting how classloading works in the JVM.  A classloader will first try to let its parent load the class you are looking for.  In order for your test to work, you need a custom class loader that will not delegate to its parent for that one class that you are testing with.

Here is an example that works in Java 8

**DummyClass.java (default package)**

```
public class DummyClass {
  static String padding = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
}
```

**Test.java (default package)**

```
import java.lang.management.ClassLoadingMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            
            URL url = Test.class.getResource("").toURI().toURL();
            System.out.println("URL = " + url);
            URL[] urls = {url};
    
            ClassLoadingMXBean loadingMXBean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
    
            List<ClassLoader> classLoaders = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("Total: " + loadingMXBean.getTotalLoadedClassCount());
            System.out.println("Active: " + loadingMXBean.getLoadedClassCount());
            System.out.println("Unloaded: " + loadingMXBean.getUnloadedClassCount());

            int i = 0;
            while ( true ) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("### Iteration " + i + " ###");
                ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls) {
                    @Override
                    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                        final Class<?> loadedClass;
                        if ( "DummyClass".equals(name) ) {
                            System.out.println (this + " - finding class " + name);
                            loadedClass = findClass(name);
                            System.out.println (this + " - loading class " + loadedClass);
                        } else {
                            // delegate to parent
                            loadedClass = this.getParent().loadClass(name);
                        }
                        return loadedClass;
                    }
                };
                
                classLoaders.add(classLoader);
                classLoader.loadClass("DummyClass");
    
                System.out.println("Total: " + loadingMXBean.getTotalLoadedClassCount());
                System.out.println("Active: " + loadingMXBean.getLoadedClassCount());
                System.out.println("Unloaded: " + loadingMXBean.getUnloadedClassCount());
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Running with `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m`, I eventually get this:

```
> ### Iteration 16318 ### 
> Test$1@531ed68e - finding class DummyClass
> Test$1@531ed68e - loading class class DummyClass
> Total: 16747 Active:
> 16747 Unloaded: 0
> ### Iteration 16319 ### 
> Test$1@6bbd4048 - finding class DummyClass 
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
> Test$1.loadClass(Test.java:42)    at Test.main(Test.java:53)
```